# Error starting SpringBoot Application in Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I found the similar questions on stackoverflow and tried to sovle the problem using this way ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738621/error-starting-applicationcontext-to-display-the-auto-configuration-report-re-r)),but it didn't work on my project.Could anybody give me some suggestions?

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:44549,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/spring-boot-dynamic-scheduled-task/target/classes:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.1/classmate-1.3.1.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.3/jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.3/jackson-annotations-2.8.3.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.3/jackson-core-2.8.3.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.5/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.5/tomcat-juli-8.5.5.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.0.Final/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.10.3.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.12.3.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.192/h2-1.4.192.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.5/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.5/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.5.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/8.5.5/tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.5.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.5.1/ecj-4.5.1.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/hand/下载/idea-IU-171.4424.56/lib/idea_rt.jar com.jege.spring.boot.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44549', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2017-05-21 23:03:43.754  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] com.jege.spring.boot.Application         : Starting Application on hand-VirtualBox with PID 20877 (/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/spring-boot-dynamic-scheduled-task/target/classes started by hand in /home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot)
2017-05-21 23:03:43.779  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] com.jege.spring.boot.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-21 23:03:44.100  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@295b2c2e: startup date [Sun May 21 23:03:44 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-21 23:03:48.822  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f84fc15b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-21 23:03:50.745  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-21 23:03:50.794  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-21 23:03:50.801  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2017-05-21 23:03:51.512  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-05-21 23:03:51.527  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-21 23:03:51.528  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7448 ms
2017-05-21 23:03:52.077  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.080  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.085  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.086  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.087  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.088  INFO 20877 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.671  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-21 23:03:52.719  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-21 23:03:52.900  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-05-21 23:03:52.905  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-21 23:03:52.911  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-05-21 23:03:53.042  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-21 23:03:53.728  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-05-21 23:03:55.213  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table t_user if exists
Hibernate: create table t_user (id bigint generated by default as identity, age integer, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
2017-05-21 23:03:55.243  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-05-21 23:03:55.306  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-21 23:03:56.822  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@295b2c2e: startup date [Sun May 21 23:03:44 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-21 23:03:56.954  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/json]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> com.jege.spring.boot.controller.UserController.json(int,int,java.lang.String)
2017-05-21 23:03:56.956  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/updateDynamicScheduledTask]}" onto public com.jege.spring.boot.json.AjaxResult com.jege.spring.boot.controller.UserController.updateDynamicScheduledTask()
2017-05-21 23:03:56.957  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/delete]}" onto public com.jege.spring.boot.json.AjaxResult com.jege.spring.boot.controller.UserController.delete(java.lang.Long)
2017-05-21 23:03:56.957  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/list]}" onto public java.lang.String com.jege.spring.boot.controller.UserController.list()
2017-05-21 23:03:56.957  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/save]}" onto public com.jege.spring.boot.json.AjaxResult com.jege.spring.boot.controller.UserController.save(com.jege.spring.boot.data.jpa.entity.User)
2017-05-21 23:03:56.961  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-05-21 23:03:56.962  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-05-21 23:03:57.053  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-21 23:03:57.064  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-21 23:03:57.181  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in commonExceptionAdvice
2017-05-21 23:03:57.238  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-21 23:03:57.960  WARN 20877 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher]: Factory method 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder '/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/src/main/java' must exist and must be a directory
2017-05-21 23:03:57.961  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-05-21 23:03:57.964  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-21 23:03:58.008  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-21 23:03:58.052  INFO 20877 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-21 23:03:58.082 ERROR 20877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher]: Factory method 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder '/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/src/main/java' must exist and must be a directory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.jege.spring.boot.Application.main(Application.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher]: Factory method 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder '/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/src/main/java' must exist and must be a directory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder '/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/src/main/java' must exist and must be a directory
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.addSourceFolder(FileSystemWatcher.java:124) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.newFileSystemWatcher(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:159) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.access$000(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:101) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration$1.getFileSystemWatcher(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:142) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher.<init>(ClassPathFileSystemWatcher.java:61) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.classPathFileSystemWatcher(LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44549', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jege.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dynamic-scheduled-task</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-dynamic-scheduled-task</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-boot-dynamic-scheduled-task</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
## JPA Settings
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql: false


#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///test
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/page/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#restart
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=src/main/java
#no need restart
#spring.devtools.restart.exclude=static/**,public/**
```

Comment: do you see the error `'/home/hand/IdeaProjects/spring-boot/src/main/java' must exist and must be a directory` What is your project directory structure?

Comment: Thanks. I run my project using mvn spring-boot:run in idea terminal comman and it works. But what's wrong using the button to debug the project in idea.

Answer (score 2):

It was caused by you configured the devtools to auto restart the application `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=src/main/java`.
if use the button to start application, you need to config the "Working directory" point to the correct project directory.